# Динамические библиотеки в отдельной папке (С++)

Tags: c++, dll, компиляция, codeblocks

Имеется проект в **Code::Blocks**, использующий библиотеки *libopengl32.a*, *libgdi32.a* и *libglfw3dll.a*. Бинарный файл, полученный в ходе компиляции данного проекта (компиляция без флага `-static`), требует наличие файлов *libstdc++-6.dll*, *libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll* и *glfw3.dll* в том же каталоге, где располагается сам исполняемый файл. Это выглядит не совсем симпатично и хотелось бы, чтобы все библиотеки искались, к примеру, в каталоге *libraries*, который бы находился в одном каталоге с исполняемым файлом, например. Возможно ли такое реализовать? И если невозможно, то насколько разумно использовать флаг `-static` при компиляции?

Comment: Не понятно при чем сдесь статические библиотеки если вы используете динамическую линковку

Comment: тут можно почитать про порядок поиска: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dynamic-link-library-search-order и https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-setdefaultdlldirectories. Статическая линковка вполне удобная вещь, многие пользуются (например телеграм)

Answer (score 2):

Под Виндоус у вас только 2 варианта:

1) добавить вашу папку с dll в PATH

2) осуществлять динамическую загрузку библиотек.

Под Линукс существует ещё и третий: скомпилировать прогу с опцией -rpath.